# AVL binary search tree rotation c++

Tags: c++, nodes

i am working on an avl tree and i think ive got the everything right, but im not sure here is my rotate right function am i doing it correcty?

```
Node* BinaryTree::rotateRight(Node *N)
{
    Node *newNode = new Node();
    newNode = N->getLeft();
    N->setLeft(newNode->getRight());
    newNode->setRight(N);
    root = newNode;
    return newNode;
}
```

Comment: Well that's going to leak memory...

Answer (score 2):

rotateRight does not need to allocate a new node. It works by manipulating the pointers to existing nodes only. Like this

```
Node* BinaryTree::rotateRight(Node *N)
{
    Node *pivot = N->getLeft();
    N->setLeft(pivot->getRight());
    pivot->setRight(N);
    return pivot;
}
```

So you were almost right apart from needlessly allocating a new node, and assigning to root for some reason.

BTW rotateRight can normally be made a static method.

Comment: With the way that you have it i get a memory leak if i only have one side of the tree with some info.

Comment: My code doesn't allocate any memory (unlike yours which does). If you have a memory leak with my code then it's because you have a bug somewhere else in your code.

Comment: ive tracked it down that method before i changed it like yours it worked fine but now it doesnt

Comment: @ john   You forgot that `pivot`'s new parent is now its former grandparent, and if that is not nullptr, then the grandparent must be updated with a new left or right child (depending on whether `node` was its left or right child) as `pivot`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code might create memory leak after `newNode = N->getLeft();`

Here's my implementation which I wrote directly over here. You can check it if its correct. I have not tested.

```
Node* BinaryTree::rotateRight(Node *N)
{
    Node *newNode = new Node();
    Node *prevLeft = N->getLeft();

    prevLeft->setRight(newNode);
    newNode->setLeft(prevLeft);
    newNode->setRight(N);
    N->setLeft(newNode);

    root = newNode;
    return newNode;
}
```

Comment: mine works and doesnt give me any memory leaks. in the line that you suggested. you are assigning the pointer to a left node of N. Also given the instructions that i was, that is how i was supposed to do it.